# Limit the number of children added in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How to limit the number of children added to **02** from firebase or java code in android.
I am going to add the child from the android application I made.
And I want to give a message to user if the number of children of **02** alreary 100.
I have tried

```
DatabaseReference dref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Root").child("Time").child(2019).child(April).child(02);
dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            numberofpatients=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

does not work;

also tried

```
dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            numberofpatients=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            numberofpatients=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            numberofpatients=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            numberofpatients=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

after getting the count i use the following to check the condition

```
    if(numberofpatients>=3){
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert=
                new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
                        FillForm.this);
        alert.setTitle("List Full");
        alert.setMessage("Select another date!");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Okay",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mDateSpinner.requestFocus();
                    }
                });

        alert.show();
    }
```

Please Help, Only the idea needed.

Comment: I have got it. my problem was checking the condition outside the `onDataChange` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through and get the number of children in child("02")

example

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Time/2019/April/02").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()==100){

                 //code here
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```